# What is the benefit of using BOOLEAN over TINYINT(1)?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

From MySQL manual, it says:

> BOOL, BOOLEAN
>
> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true:

I created a BOOLEAN column with `0` as the default value. Then I update the value to `2`. Logically, I would expect MySQL to accept either `0` or `1` since it is a boolean. However, MySQL did not issue an error or prevent me from performing the update.

If BOOLEAN works exactly the same as TINYINT(1), does it make any difference whether I use TINYINT(1) or BOOLEAN?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those two are really synonyms, so you can use them interchangeably. You won't see any difference between them.

If you want to allow 0 and 1 only, you can still use the `bit` type.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Keep in mind that `BIT` is really a bit field that holds one to sixty-four bits compactly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with other people (or you want to remind yourself), you can use the data type `BOOLEAN` to suggest that the data is only intended to take on a value of 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me there is indeed a difference.

In a table I'm using I have a column defined as a tinyint with an index on the column. When I invoke the following query "explain select * from table where column is true" it indicates that it's going to read all the rows in the table (the "possible_keys" and "ref" columns are null despite the "key" column showing the index).

Changing the query to "explain select * from table where column = 1" the index kicks in correctly, with "possible keys" and "ref" columns being assigned values and "rows" set to a much lower number.

I also tried replacing the "true" with "false" and the 1 with a 0 and got comparable results.

Taking it a step further I switched from a tinyint to an int and it made no difference.